# SQL - if record exists in tableA, then insert into tableB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using a mysql database, and I'm trying to insert a record into tableB if the product code already exists in tableA.

I think a CASE statement would work, but I can't find any further help on the web.
Here is what I have so far:

```
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA WHERE tableA.item_code = '$pcode') > 1 
THEN INSERT INTO tableB(item_id, serial_number, used) 
VALUES ('$iid','$sns','$used') END
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to write a regular old insert statement:

```
insert into tableB(item_id, serial_number, used)
select '$iid', '$sns', '$used'
where exists (select 1 from tableA where item_code = '$pcode')
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, the variables $iid, $sns and $used are calculated in the php code, not from the database table. (That said, I do need to get $iid from tableA based on a comparison to $pcode) @DerekKromm

Comment: So you should just be able to add those variables into your sql command. How are you trying to run the insert? I'm not familiar with PHP, but it should just be a matter of concatenating your SQL string together or using parameters.

Comment: Yeah, it's dropping them straight in: "INSERT INTO tableB(item_id, serial_number, used) VALUES ((SELECT tableA.item_id from va_items WHERE tableA.item_code = '$pcode'),'$sns','$used') WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE tableA.item_code = '$pcode')" Cheers @DerekKromm

Comment: oh, the sql error is giving:        You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE tableA.item_code = 'ADE12020572CH')' at line 2

Comment: that statement looks all sorts of jumbled. i assume you missed some stuff when copy/pasting/obfuscating, but try this: INSERT INTO tableB(item_id, serial_number, used) 
SELECT item_id,'$sns','$used'
from va_items 
WHERE item_code = '$pcode'

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tableB(item_id, serial_number, used)
select item_id, '$sns', 1
from tableA where item_code = '$pcode'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
INSERT INTO tableB
            (productcode)
SELECT productcode
FROM   tableC c
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT productcode
               FROM   tableA a
               WHERE  a.productcode = c.productcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you put a foreign key on the item_codes you could just insert the record in the usual way

```
INSERT INTO tableB(item_id, serial_number, used)  VALUES ('$iid','$sns','$used')
```

and catch the exception if it happens...

see: [Handling foreign key exceptions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744190/handling-foreign-key-exceptions-in-php)

the benifit of this approach is that the database is automatically enforcing the rule for you.