# how can I check foreign key constrain on delete restrict using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables **Product** and **purchase**. 
I set a `on delete restrict` FK in `product.purchase_id` column with `purchase.purchase_id` column. Then  if I try to delete product.product_id with FK, It shows error just like

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1451

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`another_bata`.`product_purchase_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_product_purchase_item_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

delete from product where product_id='158'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rima_shoe\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

> But I need a user friendly error suppose **You cant Remove this product
>   list, Beause you have already stock this product**

So I need to check this FK in php , How can I do this?

My second question.. Is it possible to delete a 'product.product_id' which already exist `on delete restrict` FK in some special case? suppose

```
DELETE p,q FROM product AS p INNER JOIN purchase AS q
WHERE p.purchase_id=q.purchase_id AND q.purchase_quan=0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Exceptions:

```
try {
    $db->query(...);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "an error occured during query";
}
```

You can also make your own Exceptions to speciallize for FK errors:

```
class ForeignKeyException extends Exception {
    public function __construct($msg = 0, $code = 0) {
        parent::__construct($msg, $code);
    }
}
```

When FK error occures, you do `throw new ForeignKeyException('FK failed');`

```
try {
    $db->query(...);
} catch (ForeignKeyException $e) {
    echo "FK error";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "general error";
}
```

**Update:**

mysqli has exceptions already:

```
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 'CODE FOR FK') {
        //...
    }
}
```

PHP mysqli exception: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php

See MYSQLI error codes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html

Another useful question: [Handling foreign key exceptions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744190/handling-foreign-key-exceptions-in-php)

**Update for 2nd question:**

Disable foreign keys by

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
<your delete query here>
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

As to your second question i guess you could check for condition with php,and if true run this query:

```
START TRANSACTION
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DELETE WHAT YOU WANT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
COMMIT
```

But foreign keys are there for a reason,playing with them arbitrarily might reserve you surprises sooner or later

Comment: Can I know? why you use `TRANSANCTION` for temporary disable FK, is this possible what will other FK on this time.. Guess there are 20+ FK when I run this query..........

Comment: Its just a way to make sure all the steps succeed,if one fails nothing will happen.